# How to change app language at run time in android

Tags: android

i change language but just changed numbers

```
    public void changeLanguage(String language){

        sharedPreferences.edit().putString(Constant.LANGUAGE_KEY, language).apply();

        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        context.getResources().getConfiguration().setLocale(locale);
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(
                context.getResources().getConfiguration(),
                context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

with this code changes **just number to Farsi but words was English**

Comment: Did you restart app or activity after change

Answer (score 3):

After changing language in activities that already opened or in back stack you must update strings.
For example in previous activities do this in `onActivityResult` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CHANGE_LANGUAGE) {

        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_SAVE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String language = prefs.getString(Constant.LANGUAGE_KEY, "en");
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        btnTitle.setText(R.string.btn_title);
        myTextView.setText(R.string.my_text_view);

        // ...
        // do this for all texts in your page

    }
}
```

And in current activity just do this after changing language:

```
btnTitle.setText(R.string.btn_title);
myTextView.setText(R.string.my_text_view);

// ...
// do this for all texts in your page
```

And add this code to your all activities

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base));
}

private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.MY_SAVE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(Constants.LANGUAGE_KEY, "en");

    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale);
    }

    return updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context, locale);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private Context updateResourcesLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Context updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}
```

Comment: @mahdisadeghi edited - add this code to all activities